# TypeError: assert.isNotEmpty is not a function with chai assert

Tags: node.js, npm, chai

I'm getting assert.isNotEmpty is not a function in mocha test when asserting with chai. I have `"chai": "^4.1.2"` defined in package.json

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;

assert.isNotEmpty({"foo" : "bar"});
```

results in:

```
TypeError: assert.isNotEmpty is not a function
```

What am I not seeing?

Comment: Do the other *assert* functions work correctly?
Try assert.equal(1, 1,)

Comment: Try `let chai = require('chai'); chai.assert.isNotEmpty(...)`.

Comment: @BogdanBiv, yes others work.

Comment: @alexmac same error with that

Comment: Have you tried any older version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an npm problem. By running `npm list` I saw the error

`npm ERR! invalid: chai@3.5.0 /.../node_modules/chai`

For some reason npm was stuck with an error with an older version. I deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and run npm install again and got it working.